# Embed my swf file on html

Tags: html, flash, mobile

I want to embed my swf-file via html. This is a part of my code. The problem is that the file shows up only on desktop and not on mobile devices. I need it to show on mobile devices too. Where is my mistake?

```
<center><object data="flickr_lung.swf" width="500" height="500"></object></center>
```

Comment: on which mobile device you tried? and browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tried it on all mobile devices even on tabs..

Comment: Flash is not supported in mobile devices. Try to use an HTML(5) alternative ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure how you missed the memo on this...it's been going on for near a decade at this point...but I'll explain anyway.

Practically no common mobile device browsers support **flash player** and the **.swf format**. In general they don't typically support plugin technology.

**Option 1**: Flash (the authoring tool, distinct from flash player) can output HTML/CSS/JS type content instead of the .swf format. This may take some mucking about with your project, it's new stuff to learn and deal with. But worth it.

**Option 2**: Progressive enhancement. I have flash sites that I made before mobiles even were around that still work great to this day because I progressively enhanced them by outputting a simpler HTML version of the same content as a the "backup" content to the swf. Ironically that simple HTML version is often more usable on tiny devices than many modern responsive sites are...but I digress...

**Option 3**: If what you're trying to build happens to be some sort of web-app, Flash is perfectly capable of producing mobile apps. So they could use said app as an actual app instead of a browser driven app. Now your progressively enhanced HTML backup content can point them to the app.

**Option 4**: Flash is a specialized thing. If you actually don't need to be using and your site is build-able without it then you can just build a normal website in HTML/CSS/JS.